# Add json objects as BLOB in database with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, json, entity-framework

I am new with the entity framework. I have a dashboard with widgets and this is my table in Microsoft SQL server. [image: Table]

The reason I have widgets as a blob and not as a seperated entity is because I am not gonna query on the widgets table. Only data like `SELECT * FROM Dashboard WHERE dashboardid =x`

This is my DashboardDAL class:

```
public class DashboardDAL
{
    public Dashboard GetDashboardPerUser()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string AddWidget()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I want to add a widget with the entity framework. A Json object of a widget looks like this:

`{name:"Weather", dashboardid:"2", userID:"4", "x":1,"y":0,"width":3,"height":1}`

How can I add a widget object and save it as a BLOB in the database?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a string.  Use a string property on an entity to store it with EF.  This will map to a NVARCHAR(MAX) column in SQL Server, which is the correct type for storing JSON in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick and I changed the datatype of widgets.